# Get more details of Cloud Firestore usage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase (Cloud Firestore regarding data) as backend of a website I'm developing and I see that the number of documents reading is higher than it should be.

Is there a way to get the details of all requests made on the server for a giving period? I would like to identify which of my requests are costful/executed too often.

I tried to find a simple answer to my question but couldn't find something clear.

Comment: What do you mean "is higher than it should be"?  What are the differences?

Comment: I'm currently the single user as I'm still in development and I have approximately 1000 documents read / day whereas it's a simple app with a really low amount of data, so it will be a huge issue on production. 
I would like to see some details on it, like a log of each request received by the server to be able to identify what is the cause of this.

Comment: There is no specific accounting for billed Firestore operations.  The most common cause of unexpected reads comes from use of the Firestore console.  Whenever the console reads a document, you will be billed.  It can be expensive to leave the console open on a busy collection, as each realtime update of a document will cost a read.

Comment: I think it comes mainly from some implementations in my code. I identified some fixes I'm going to make but that's not the point.
I would like to see which requests have been received by the server on a given period, or which documents have been read during this time but I don't know if it's possible.